# Socket io only emits data upon page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, page-refresh

Within an express.js project I am attempting to emit data from the nodeJS server to the client.

Upon reaching the page the terminal (from which I initiated the server) states a user has connected via socket. However upon running the function that contains the socket emit function, nothing occurs.

Only upon reloading the webpage does the emitted data appear in the html and terminal console logs.

Below is the code triggering the socket from within a Callback function, in app.js

```
foo(function(fooCallback) {
    console.log('Callback triggered');

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('about to send data via socket');
        io.sockets.emit('person', { 'name': 'Jack Smith' });

    });
});
```

global.js - (client side js loaded after jquery and socket scripts)

```
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('person', function(socket){
        console.log('client recieved something from socket');
        var personName = socket.name;
        $('#person').html(personName);
    });
```

Why is data only being emitted when the webpage is reloaded, rather than automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('about to send data via socket');
    io.sockets.emit('person', { 'name': 'Jack Smith' });
});
```

You say that you only want to run `io.sockets.emit('person', { 'name': 'Jack Smith' });` when the `io` variable first connects. Try changing this to:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('about to send data via socket');
});

io.sockets.emit('person', { 'name': 'Jack Smith' });
```

Comment: But, how is this possibly going to work?  At the point `io.sockets.emit()` runs, it is during server initialization so there will be no sockets connected yet so it will do nothing.  I wonder if it's supposed to be inside the connection callback like it was, but instead it should be `socket.emit(...)` so it only sends to the  just connected socket?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the server spreads the connection message too late for you app to detect that on the first load. I'm not sure why you're using such that foo callback function. Your io.on connect logic should go directly inside your main js file. A possible way around, however, is to initialize your var io = io(); inside that foo function